# how to add entries for allowed hosts in the referrer filter node

Tags: aem

To prevent cross site request forgery, I want to try with **referrer filter**, and in the allowed hosts section, I want to add my trustable websites for instance **site1.com, site2.com, site3.com** etc.
My doubt is like do we need to specify **https** and all in the allowed host entry as below

```
       https://site1.com  or 
       specifying it as site1.com would do.
```

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the hostname is enough. site1.com will get you through. AEM will take care of both http and https with the hostname alone. By specifying the protocol explicitly , you can add restriction to allow requests from only, let's say, https referer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)  Abhishek do we have any documentation for this

Comment: There is some documentation here https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security-checklist.html#Protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery. But this doesn't clearly states that protocol is optional. My current application uses this config without protocol and it works pretty well.